# What shows the person's authority on a domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, top-level-domains

Like if you own a property, your property papers shows its your property. No-one can claim that it's their property, not yours because you are the one got papers.

Anyway, what shows your authority on a domain name? I know the whois record has got all the info about the domain owner, but what is the important thing in the records that if you lose it, you can lose your domain?

Is it the email or home address? What is main thing?

e.g. If my email is hacked then can the hacker could claim my domain name or if I move to a new house and the people shifted in that house can they claim the domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you buy a domain name, there are records showing you as the domain name owner. Just because someone impersonates you, it doesn't mean they can own your property. Just like your car, if someone claims to be you, that doesn't mean they can drive off with your car.

Only you can assign the domain name to an IP address. Only you can buy a SSL certificate for that domain name.

If they hack your email, they can request the registrar to change the IP address assigned to your domain name but that would set all kinds of red flags, such as why don't you do this yourself? Response emails will still go to your email address so they would have to be intercepted each time. Your DNS account should be password protected, as well as with two-factor authentication.

And when you wake up one morning to find your domain name not assigned to your IP, you call your registrar who will then verify your contact information and find out what's going on.

Comment: I see ok if some one hacks my cpanel, email, and my account on the godaddy and if i cant recover then and he start using my domain for his personal use how can i get the domain back???

Comment: @DannyRock As I said, you call or email them. They can tell from access logs what's going on but, if you ever have that many problems, you've got more issues to worry about than this.

Comment: Ok got ya n nah man m not that much noob i just started learning security so thinking of worst scenarios

Comment: So in nutshell the email address is the main thing right...!!! Or the address n phone numbers are also